# Simple ternary operator throwing unexpected error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a React app which contains links to subroutes, and I use the subdomain/path to populate the props on each detail page.

In other words, when a user navigates to a page I use `pathname` to populate things like the page title and contents. One of the pages/routes contains a name/title which is normally written in upper camel casing ("SoCal"), so I use following code which contains a ternary operator that determines if `location = "socal"` and if it does, I want the `location` variable to be set to "SoCal" so that when I use `<h1>{location}</h1>` to populate the page title, it will be displayed correctly.

The problem is that when I use the ternary operator it *always* sets the location to SoCal, even if the original value of `location` was Texas (for example). It seems like I'm doing something wrong, but can't see what it is.

```
var location = titleCase(window.location.pathname.replace("/", ""));

function detailPage() {
  const [filter] = useState(location.toLowerCase());
  location = "socal" ? location = "SoCal" : location;
  console.log(location)
```

Note that in the above example, I'm using `=` instead of `===` as you would expect because when I use `===` the code breaks and returns the error message:

> "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
> expression. (no-unused-expressions)"

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your ternary operator is incorrect. You will want to use the following syntax to leverage ternary operators in your code.

It should follow as such:

```
variable = (conditional statement) ? (value if true) : (value if false)
```

In your case.

```
location = location === "socal" ? "SoCal" : location
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```js
location = "socal" ? location = "SoCal" : location;
```

The first part of a ternary statement is a condition check. You are checking whether the value of "socal" is true of false. You're also doing an assignment in the operator which isn't allowed.